# How can I uninstall all versions of a single Python package on my system?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed my Python package `hwrt` in a number of different ways:

- `pip install hwrt --user`
- `sudo pip install hwrt`
- `sudo -H pip install hwrt`
- `python setup.py install --user`
- `sudo python setup.py install --user`
- All of the above with Python 3

I also installed different versions of it (each time when I updated it). Now I have this single package multiple times on my system.

```
find . -type d | grep hwrt
./python2.7/dist-packages/hwrt-0.1.221.dist-info
./python2.7/dist-packages/hwrt-0.1.218-py2.7.egg-info
./python3.4/dist-packages/hwrt
./python3.4/dist-packages/hwrt/templates
./python3.4/dist-packages/hwrt/misc
./python3.4/dist-packages/hwrt/__pycache__
./python3.4/dist-packages/hwrt-0.1.205.egg-info
```

I already executed `sudo pip uninstall hwrt` multiple times. Each time one of those packages was removed.

Is there a way to uninstall all packages with the name `hwrt` (and no other packages) with a single command?

Comment: manually delete all, and try importing, it will give an error. Then install with one method

Comment: @sinhayash I know that I can do that. In fact, I always did this by now. But my question is if there is a better way.

Comment: Right now I remove versions of the package I'm developing by repeatedly running `pip uninstall` which picks off one version each time, it's not satisfactory, is there really no better way?